# Function/Algorithm to redistribute data evenly betwen processes

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, load-balancing

I have a global array, A, whose elements are initially spread unevenly over multiple processes in an MPI program. In the interests of load-balancing, I'd like to redistribute the elements of A so that each process holds approximately the same number of elements. There is a great deal of freedom in the rearrangement because the ordering of the elements of A is unimportant - I am not concerned with which elements of A end up on which process. I would, of course, like to achieve the transfer as fast as possible.

Is there a canonical name for this problem, a standard solution, or an MPI function which can solve it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is referred to as 'load balancing', as you already said.

There is no direct MPI function, you need to do some arithmetic calculations and sending/receiving yourself. However there are quite a couple libraries out there, which give well partitioned domains and such. [Metis](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) is very popular for mesh or graph-based partitoned.

In your case the difficulty arises from the fact, that all ranks may need to send (and receive) just parts of their data to (from) differing number of ranks. If you have the possibility to get the complete global A on one rank first you could just scatter it with `MPI_Scatter`. Otherwise you need to do some calculation:

- First send (MPI_Allgather) the element count of all ranks to every rank
- Count how many elements each rank should send (receive) and to (from) whom.
- Do the sending/receiving or  use one-sided communication.